# Will_paginate failing to load pages, bad URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I am trying to implement the will_paginate gem with AJAX infinite scrolling in a project. When attempting to use it, I receive in the following error in the JS console.

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (filter, line 0)
>
> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (filter, line 0)

What I know:

- I have used this exact code in another project and it has worked flawlessly.
- My vehicle#index is filtering the initial input with a scope and I suspect this is the reason for the error. I do not know how to pass it.

**Here is the stack trace:**

```
Started GET "/ajax-loader.gif" for ::1 at 2016-01-24 09:30:51 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/ajax-loader.gif"):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/static.rb:124:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/jon/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/jon/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/jon/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/jon/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (20.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (134.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (56.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/jon/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (129.3ms)


Started GET "/vehicles/filter?page=2&_=1453645847210" for ::1 at 2016-01-24 09:30:52 -0500
Processing by VehiclesController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "_"=>"1453645847210", "id"=>"filter"}
  Vehicle Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "vehicles".* FROM "vehicles" WHERE "vehicles"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
  Rendered public/404.html (0.6ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 55ms (Views: 52.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#vehicles').append('<%= j render @vehicles %>');
<% if @vehicles.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @vehicles %>');
<% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

**pagination.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
    return $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      var more_posts_url;
      more_posts_url = $('.pagination a.next_page').attr('href');
      if (more_posts_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60) {
        $('.pagination').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />');
        $.getScript(more_posts_url);
      }
      return;
    });
  }
});
```

**routes.rb**

```
...
  resources :vehicles do
    collection do
      post 'filter' => 'vehicles#index'
    end
    member do
      get 're_edit' => 'vehicles#re_edit'
      post 'resubmit' => 'vehicles#resubmit'
      patch 'resubmit' => 'vehicles#resubmit'
    end
  end
...
```

**vehicles_controller.rb**

```
def index
  scope = Vehicle.approved
  scope = scope.filter_by_make(params[:makes]) if params[:makes].present?
  scope = scope.filter_by_year(params[:years]) if params[:years].present?

  @vehicles = scope.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 6).order('created_at DESC')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<section id="vehicles" class="content">
  <% @vehicles.each do |vehicle| %>
    <div>
      <h2><%= link_to "#{vehicle.make} #{vehicle.model}", vehicle %></h2>
        <%= image_tag(vehicle.primary_image.image, class: "img-responsive") if vehicle.primary_image %>
        <p><%= vehicle.year %> <%= vehicle.make %> <%= vehicle.model %></p>
        <%= link_to "View Details", vehicle, class: "details" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</section>
 
<div id="infinite-scrolling">
  <%= will_paginate %>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't  Vehicle.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 6).order('created_at DESC') supposed to be  scope.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 6).order('created_at DESC')?

Comment: Try to use `j_will_paginate`

Comment: @PeterdeRidder Yes that is correct. My mistake. I changed that in my dev environment to test more records. I'll edit the code, thanks.

Comment: One more tip, don't use scope as local variable. It is actually a reserved word. For example, if you add a binding.pry in your index action and you call scope, the result is not the same as you would expect. I'm not saying it will cause problems, but it's not a good practice. Your controller action could be cleaner, I would use Vehicle.approved.by_year(params[:year]).by_makes(params[:makes]) and add 2 scopes to your Vehicle class. I would also use another name for makes, since it is not self explanatory.

Comment: @PeterdeRidder Thanks for the advice. I will be sure to fix this.